# How to add a "deployment project" in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, build, web-deployment-project

I understand the concept: building one project which forces other builds and concentrate all the bins into one target directory.

I am not able to add a "deployment project" to my solution successfully.

Are there conditions or restrictions to adding deployment project?
Is it related to web projects only? Can I do the same in a solutions without having web project?

[image]

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  Under [add project] I have the following tree: "Other Project Types", "Setup and Deployment", "Visual Studio Installer".  Under there I have { Setup Project, Web Setup Project, Merge Module Project, Setup Wizard, CAB project}.  Which version of VStudio 2010 are you using?  What is under "Other Project Types"?

Comment: VS2010 professional
I added a photo, but I remember it was just right click on any project or on the sln itself